# Построить линии между точками(вершинами) WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Есть код, он записывает в массив координаты сделанных точек в canvas

Как мне теперь по этим точкам нарисовать многоугольник?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам уже правильно сказали, что вам нужно сохранять не строки (боже упаси!), а объекты типа `Point`.

Далее, массив — совершенно неподходящая структура данных в вашем случае. (Я бы сказал, массивы не нужны практически никогда.) Вам нужен `List<Point>`.

Теперь ваш код будет иметь такой вид:

```
List<Point> markedPoints = new List<Point>();

private void cnv_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{            
    Point pt = e.GetPosition((Canvas)sender); // позиция нужна относительно канваса, да?
    markedPoints.Add(pt);
    if (markedPoints.Count >= 5)
    {
        // окей, набралось по крайней мере 5 точек
        // рисуйте фигуру любым подходящим для вас способом
    }
}
```

Comment: Если рисовать через класс polygon, то после создания экземляра как на него привязать список координат?

Comment: @SOFL: Ну, поскольку вы получаете всё равно обновления списка точек, то `polygon.Points = new PointCollection(markedPoints)`. Вот пример кода: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_9

Comment: Все получилось, добавил pg.Points = new PointCollection(markedPoints); и в условие  pg.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

                inkc.Children.Add(pg);

Comment: Теперь про алгоритм. Создаем список сначала, затем создаем переменную в которую будут записываться значения координат, полученные с полотна, эта строка - markedPoints.Add(pt), добавляет в список полученные координаты. pg.Points = new PointCollection(markedPoints), эта строка как я понял накидывает на нашу объявленный объект полигона точки которые перехватил с полотна. pg.Stroke = Brushes.Black это логично рисует линию,  inkc.Children.Add(pg) - вот эту строчку не понял, что такое чилдрен не в курсе

Comment: И все же, почему удобнее использовать как вы написали, списки во многих случаях, а не массивы?

Comment: @SOFL: У каждого элемента есть вложенные подэлементы. Children — это они и есть. Строка `inkc.Children.Add(pg)` добавляет `pg` как подэлемент `inkc`. Поскольку `inkc` есть в вашем окне, то его подэлементы тоже будут показаны там.

Comment: @SOFL: Список удобнее использовать потому, что обычно у вас есть не все элементы, а только часть их, и вы хотите добавлять их по одному. И вы не знаете максимальное количество элементов заранее. Для таких случаев массив плохо подходит.

Answer (score 3):

Лучше будет создать массив типа Point

```
 Point[] myArr = new Point[5];
```

вместо

```
 string[] myArr = new string[5];
```

после этого можно будет передавать его элементы функции построения многоугольника

Comment: И как в такой массив записывать координаты? + нельзя применить к типу класса point

Comment: `myArr[i] = e.GetPosition(this);`

Comment: Так все элементы тогда будут равны  первой координате

Comment: Для проверки вывожу координаты в lb1.Content = pt.X.ToString() + ", " + pt.Y.ToString(); координата перезаписывается каждый раз, в моем способе добавляется следующая

Comment: Вы можете после каждого события мышки инкрементировать i, тогда каждый элемент будет равен соответствующей координате, естественно, нужно избежать выхода за пределы массива

Comment: i += e.ClickCount;

Comment: Добавил чтобы после каждого клика увеличивалось, все равно через проверку не могу вывести все координаты. Но больше 4 щелчков не дает сделать, за пределы границы выкидывает - как и должно быть